# Java Spring many to one thymeleaf error . How can i solve it?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, many-to-one

The application works when database is empty.If I add a user then i can not add an animal .Can you help me ? I have 2 class User and Animal .

AnimalController.java

```
    public String showAnimalNewForm(Model model){
        List<User> listUsers = userService.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("listUsers",listUsers);
        model.addAttribute("animal",new Animal());
        return "animal_form";
    }
```

Here i am trynig to show users . Animal have to has one owner.
animal_form.html

```
            <div class="form-group raw">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"> User: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8" style="float: right;">
                    <select class="form-control" th:field="*{user}" >
                        <th:block th:each="user : ${listUsers}">
                            <option th:text="${user.name}" th:value="${user.id}">
                            </option>
                        </th:block>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Error

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Apr 10 11:16:51 TRT 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/animal_form.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/animal_form.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "user.name" (template: "animal_form" - line 57, col 37)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "user.name" (template: "animal_form" - line 57, col 37)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.processIterationModel(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:367)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.process(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:221)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:322)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:220)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:164)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on object of type 'com.vet.model.User' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:338)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:265)
```

All code here: **https://github.com/Furkan-Ahmet-Ozdemir/Spring-vet**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly what is stated in error message: "Property or field 'name' cannot be found on object of type 'com.vet.model.User'". Your class User has no 'name' field, so probably it is misprint: it has 'firstName' and 'lastName' fields instead.

Answer (score 0):

For the future generations: Had a similar issue - Fixed it by creating a getter for the list that stores my associations.